# Generating new (not renewed) SSL Certificates with "letsencrypt certonly" in non-interactive mode

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

The following command leads to a series of reasonable prompts for information such as company information, contact info, etc... I'd like to be able to run it but pass that information as either parameters or a config file but I can't find out how from the docs (https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#command-line-options). Any ideas?

```
letsencrypt certonly \
--webroot -w /letsencrypt/challenges/ \
--text --renew-by-default --agree-tos \
  $domain_args \
 --email=$EMAIL
```

Note that I am not trying to renew but to generate fresh new certificates.

Thank you

Comment: [ployst/letsencrypt](https://hub.docker.com/r/ployst/letsencrypt/) is a docker image that makes this simpler for Kubernetes. It saves the certificate as a secret and does a rolling restart on your deployment so you can reload.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm using. The problem is generating a new cert without the prompts.

Comment: I don't recall seeing prompts when using their new cert script. Try their instructions instead of calling letsencrypt manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `--noninteractive` flag to letsencrypt. According to the document that you linked to, that will produce an error telling you which other flags are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When using [ployst/letsencrypt](https://hub.docker.com/r/ployst/letsencrypt/) the initial certificate creation can be done using their internal scripts. Those scripts already pass all the right arguments to make this an automated process and not an interactive one. The documentation has the following two steps that both create the certificate and apply it as a secret.

If your environment variables are already set properly, you don't even have to pass `-c 'EMAIL=....` etc.

> **Generate a new set of certs**
>
> Once this container is running you can generate new certificates
>   using:
>
> ```
> kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bash -c 'EMAIL=fred@fred.com DOMAINS=example.com foo.example.com ./fetch_certs.sh'
> ```
>
> **Save the set of certificates as a secret**
>
> ```
> kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bash -c 'DOMAINS=example.com foo.example.com ./save_certs.sh'
> ```